# IF Database not Exists then Truncate command giving error in SQL SERVER 2016 but its working fine in lower version in SQL Server .. please suggest

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, truncate

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Master..SysDatabases WHERE  [name] = 'abcd')
BEGIN
    TRUNCATE TABLE abcd.dbo.ascf  
END
```

Comment: What's the problem here?

Comment: Why don't you check if `ascf` exists, not the database. `IF OBJECT_ID('abcd.dbo.ascf', 'U') IS NOT NULL TRUNCATE TABLE abcd.dbo.ascf;`

Comment: Also, _not working_ is far too broad, what's not working? what error you get?. Care to what you write, cause the database may exists but the table not. Please edit your question and include the error message, and describe what are you really trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

As a one of the workarounds:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Master..SysDatabases WHERE  [name] = 'abcd')
BEGIN
    EXEC ('TRUNCATE TABLE abcd.dbo.ascf')
END
```

Lowering of compatibility level to SQL 2008 - SQL2014 will not help.